# How to set SELinux enforcing, config file not found?

Tags: root-access, linux, selinux, safety-net

I have Samsung Galaxy J7 Core (SM-J701F), I'm running Magisk on my device and I ran the SafteyNet test and it failed. While trying to solve this I tried to change **selinux** state to **enforced** by editing `/etc/selinux.config`. But when I opened the folder there was no such file!

When I run `getenforce` command it gives me "permissive". Is this a problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `permissive` SELinux could be one of the reasons of failed SafetyNET test <sup>([1](https://koz.io/inside-safetynet/))</sup>. So you need to set it `enforcing`. However Android uses a modified version of [libselinux](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/blob/libselinux-2.9/libselinux/include/selinux/selinux.h#L498), not dependent on `/etc/selinux/config` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/selinux/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r39/README.android#25))</sup>. On Android SELinux is configured when building ROM, and enforced by `init` when booting ROM. However if you have root, you can use `setenforce` command (located under `/system/bin`) or write directly to Kernel Configuration File (`/sys/fs/selinux/enforce`). But make sure you have a working SE policy before enforcing, or you may get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I did a factory reset to solve this and then install everything as it was before and it's solved